# Migrating data, from latin1 charset to UTF-8

Tags: php, wordpress, migration

I'm trying to move over some fish species information profiles from a bespoke CMS using `latin1` charset to a WordPress customised (custom post type, with numerous meta fields) database which uses `UTF-8`.

On top of that, the old CMS uses some odd bbCode bits.

Basically, I'm looking for a function which will do this:

- Take information from my old database with `latin1_swedish_ci` collation (and `latin1` charset)
- Convert all of the non-standard characters (we have characters from languages including but not exclusive of Croatian, Czech, Spanish, French and German) to HTML entities such as `&aacute;` (numbers like `&134;` fine too).
- Convert all of the bbCode (see below) to HTML
- Convert `'` and `"` to HTML entities
- Return the information with `utf-8` charset to my new database

The bbCode `to` and `from` are:

```
$search = array( '[i]', '[/i]', '[b]', '[/b]', '[pl]', '[/pl]' );
$replace = array( '<i>', '</i>', '<strong>', '</strong>', '', '' );
```

The function that I've tried so far is:

```
$search = array( '[i]', '[/i]', '[b]', '[/b]', '[pl]', '[/pl]' );
$replace = array( '<i>', '</i>', '<strong>', '</strong>', '', '' );

function _convert($content) { 
    if(!mb_check_encoding($content, 'UTF-8') 
        OR !($content === mb_convert_encoding(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8' ), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-32'))) { 

        $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8'); 

        if (mb_check_encoding($content, 'UTF-8')) { 
            return $content;
        } else { 
            echo "<p>Couldn't convert to UTF-8.</p>";
        } 
    } 
} 

function _clean($content) {
    $content = _convert( $content );
    /* edited out because otherwise all HTML appears as &lt;html&gt; rather than <html>
    //$content = htmlentities( $content, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8" );
    $content = str_replace( $search, $replace, $content );

    return $content;
}
```

However this is stopping some fields from being imported to the new database and isn't replacing the bbCode.

If I use the following code, it mostly works:

`$var = str_replace( $search, $replace, htmlentities( $row["var"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8" ) );`

However, certain fields containing what I think are Czech/Croatian characters don't appear at all.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can, in the order listed above, successfully convert the information from the "old format" to the new?

Comment: Converting from latin1 to `&134;` is not exactly "using UTF-8". Why this instead of real UTF-8?

Comment: I must admit I don't really know anything about charsets or understand the way they work. The "key fact" behind this post is essentially this: when I've been migrating to my new database, certain fields haven't been recognised by WordPress. When I've whittled down the problem, I've found that it's the non-standard characters which are causing problems. Looking into it further, I presumed - with guidance from this post [ http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40770/problem-with-serialized-arrays-in-custom-meta ] - that it would be because of the charset differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say if you want to convert all your non-ASCII characters you won't need to do any `latin1` to `UTF-8` conversion what so ever. Let's say you run a function such as `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` on your data, then all non-ASCII characters will be replaced with their corresponding entity code.

Basically, after this step, there shouldn't be any characters left that needs conversion to `UTF-8`. Also, if you wanted to convert your `latin1` encoding string into `UTF-8` i strongly suspect `utf8_encode` will du just fine.

PS. When it comes to converting `bbCode` into `HTML` I would recommend using regular expressions instead. For example you could do it all in a line like this:

```
$html_data = preg_replace('/\[(/?[a-z]+)\]/i', '<$1>', $bb_code_data);
```